# Back button not responsive when the splash screen is showing (new Splash API for Android 12)

Tags: android, back-button, android-12, android-splashscreen

Since the new Android Splash Screen API for Android 12, **the back button is no longer responsive while the splash screen is showing**, it looks like the UI thread has taken over completely and there is no way I can reenable the back button, this is a problem, for example, if a user accidentally opens the application, he normally clicks the back button and it's solved immediately the app closes, (or at least that was the behavior of my app before this new API), but now this a bad UX.

So I'm wondering if you have found a way to solve this and enable the Back button while the splash screen is showing while the data is loading?

I have tested many tutorials and I have downloaded the source code, and in all of them, the back button is not responsive.

For example this one:
https://github.com/philipplackner/SplashScreenAndroid12

Thank you for your help, it's really appreciated.

Comment: Hello, did you find anything to go forward today ?